# Approach for handling null values of related objects when adding new entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am passing a POCO object into a method that will create a new entity.  Some of the fields in the DB allow null.  Creating the entity, I have to do a lookup based on one of the fields.  Well, this lookup might return null, which wouldnt let me reference its properties during the primary entity addition.  See below for code

```
Location origin = new Location()
{
    Order = o,
    LocationTypeKey = ctx.LocationTypes.Where(a => a.TypeName == "Origin").First().LocationTypeId,
    Address1 = " test address 1",
    Address2 = " test Address 2",
    City = oi.OriginCity,
    StateKey = ctx.States.Where(a => a.StateName == oi.OriginState).First() == null ? 9999 : ctx.States.Where(a => a.StateName == oi.OriginState).First().StateId,
    CountryKey = ctx.Countries.Where(a => a.CountryName == oi.OriginCountry).First().CountryId
};
ctx.Locations.Add(origin);
```

Notice I am trying to default a value for StateKey if my POCO value for State cant result in a matching value in the lookup table (States).

This isnt working and I still get an exception in the caller dealing with "Sequence contains no entites".  As I step through the code, its failing on that line where I am trying the conditional null check.

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `.First()` method will fail if you have no entities. A simple fix is to call `.FirstOrDefault()` instead.

However, it's worth noting that your code as it is written does a lot more work than it needs to--five round-trips to the database, two of which are duplicates, and all of which pull in more information than you need.

More importantly, it seems like a Really Bad Idea™ to use 9999 as a code for there being no corresponding state/country. Why not have a nullable key value, instead?

Change `StateKey` and `CountryKey` to nullable ints, then here's an improved version:

```
Location origin = new Location()
{
    Order = o,
    LocationTypeKey = ctx.LocationTypes
        .Where(a => a.TypeName == "Origin")
        .Select(a => a.LocationTypeId)
        .First(),
    Address1 = " test address 1",
    Address2 = " test Address 2",
    City = oi.OriginCity,
    StateKey = ctx.States.Where(a => a.StateName == oi.OriginState)
        .Select(a => (int?)a.StateId)
        .FirstOrDefault(),
    CountryKey = ctx.Countries.Where(a => a.CountryName == oi.OriginCountry)
        .Select(a => (int?)a.CountryId)
        .FirstOrDefault()
};
```

Comment: This seems better, thanks!  Im trying it now.  [update] YES, this works and yes, its simpler than what I was going to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good answers here suggesting `FirstOrDefault()` which will protect from null values; however, here is another option:

```
StateKey = ctx.States
              .Where(a => a.StateName == oi.OriginState).Any() 
              ? ctx.States.Where(a => a.StateName == oi.OriginState).FirstOrDefault().StateId
              :9999,
```

Comment: I think you have to reverse the true/false condition

Comment: @ssilas777 Thanks but I just copied it from the OP.  I don't know what their implementation logic is.

Comment: OP is checking for null, but your are checking for not null

Comment: I see what you mean, good catch.  Thanks for updating it, too.  It was just more of a demo of `.Any()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.FirstOrDefault()`,  It will return `null` if there is no data but `.First()` will only throw an exception

```
 StateKey = ctx.States.Where(a => a.StateName == oi.OriginState).FirstOrDefault() == null ? 9999 : ctx.States.Where(a => a.StateName == oi.OriginState).First().StateId
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is what I want to use. Notice Im comparing count instead of null

```
        Location origin = new Location()
        {
            Order = o,
            LocationTypeKey = ctx.LocationTypes.Where(a => a.TypeName == "Origin").First().LocationTypeId,
            Address1 = " test address 1",
            Address2 = " test Address 2",
            City = oi.OriginCity,
            StateKey = ctx.States.Where(a => a.StateName == oi.OriginState).Count() == 0 ? 9999 : ctx.States.Where(a => a.StateName == oi.OriginState).First().StateId,
            CountryKey = ctx.Countries.Where(a => a.CountryName == oi.OriginCountry).First().CountryId
        };
        ctx.Locations.Add(origin);
```